# How to redirect C# trace and debug info to a file?

Tags: c#, powershell

I've enabled logging trace in a C# program

```
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>  
{
    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
    logging.AddConsole(o => o.LogToStandardErrorThreshold = LogLevel.Trace);
}
```

However, the following command doesn't redirect the trace/debug info to the file

```
myprogram | tee -filepath $name
```

And the following approach doesn't work either?

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\logs\output.log"; myprogram; Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on the current situation? For example, does `myprogram` outpt anything if started without redirecting output? Does the `tee`-approach still output to console, instead of the file or is there no output at all? Do you understand what `LogToStandardErrorThreshold` means? (In lack of this information a guess: I don't know about `Start-Transcript` other that it can be tricky, but since all your output is supposed to go to stderr, you would need to use `myprogram 2>&1|tee ...`)

Comment: Yes, myprogram prints a lot of trace and debug logs on the screen but they are not written to the file.

Comment: Then try `myprogram 2>&1| tee -filepath $name`. That redirects stderr, which you are writing to per `LogToStandardErrorThreshold=LogLevel.Trace` to stdout, which is then piped to `tee`.